# Why include the class name when referring to a static variable?

Tags: java, variables, static

While doing some Java homework I answered a question by writing an instance method, in the method I made use of some `static final` variables that belonged to the class the method was in. I wrote the static variable names without prefixing them with the class' name, for example:

```
for(int i=0; i < MY_STATIC_VARIABLE; i++)
```

instead of

```
for(int i=0; i < MyClass.MY_STATIC_VARIABLE; i++)
```

This compliled and worked correctly. It was only later that I noticed I had forgotten to prefix the class' name. Does it matter whether I include the class name or not? Does a `static final` variable act like a global variable within the context of its class?

Comment: "global variable within (some context)" is an oxymoron. If it's just within a context, then it isn't global ;-)

Comment: @Joachim Sauer You know what I mean ;-)

Comment: I do, but I happen to value precise terminology. Especially in technical discussion.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer it was qualified with the words '...act like a...'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does it matter whether I include the class name or not?

To your teacher, and future people reviewing code at companies you end up working for, maybe.  But maybe not - If I were reviewing your code, I'd suggest leaving out the class name in this case.

To the compiler, no, it doesn't matter.

> Does a static final variable act like a global variable within the context of it's class?

Sure does

Comment: Prefixing a locally declared static with it's qualifying class name (while not syntactically incorrect) would actually raise an eyebrow if I were reviewing (unless there was a reason for it i.e. similarly named statically imported variables).

Comment: @hoipolloi By 'locally declared static' do you mean the static was declared in the same class as the instance method that is referencing it? Or the static was declared within the instance method?

Comment: @MrMisterMan: I think we all mean within the class.  "qualifying class name" wouldn't make sense for a static declared within the method, because it wouldn't be a member variable.  (is that legal in Java?  I know it is in C++, but I would be surprised if it was in Java...)

Comment: @hoipolloi I thought that's what you meant but I just wanted to check. I've no idea if it's legal in Java, I'm still learning!

Comment: @MrMisterMan: I meant a static declared within the current class. You cannot declare static variables within a method in Java.

Answer (score 4):

> Does a `static final` variable act like a global variable within the context of its class?

Yes, all `static` class-level members are accessible throughout the class's code (`final` or otherwise), and they don't need to be prefixed with the class name. Including it or not is a style preference.

What's less obvious is that within an instance method, you could use `this.MY_STATIC_VARIABLE` and the compiler would be perfectly happy, even though `MY_STATIC_VARIABLE` isn't an instance field. (With public static fields, you can do that with any instance reference, not just `this`.) You can do the same thing with `static` methods. But it's horribly misleading to anyone reading the code. :-) Still technically a style preference, but I'd strongly recommend against it. Just mentioning it in case you end up reading code that looks like it must have a bug in it.

Answer (score 3):

Like Joey already said, if you are within the class you can access it unqualified. If you are however using it from another class then you should use the classname instead of a instance to access it, to make it clear that it is a static variable/constant.

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass();
instance.MY_STATIC_VARIABLE //not good
MyClass.MY_STATIC_VARIABLE  //good
```

Answer (score 1):

It compiles fine because of -- as you figured out -- the static final variable is in the same class. This means that the variable is in the "scope" of the code. And it simply doesn't matter if you include the prefix or not. Only when you want to access static varialbes from another class as the current, you have to say in which class the variable is located.

It is pretty much the same as saying `this` or not. eg:

```
private String secret;
public String getSecret()
{
    return this.secret;
}
```

Or

```
private String secret;
public String getSecret()
{
    return secret;
}
```

This is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the reviewer point of view (even you in the future :-) ), it is also good to keep the class name prefix for a quick refactoring when needed. It will spare you the changes all over your source code. Consider that too!

Answer (score 1):

To clarify my comments:

```
import static java.math.BigDecimal.TEN;
...

public class Foo {

    private static int COUNT = 0;
    private static BigDecimal FIVE = new BigDecimal(5);
    private BigDecimal height;

    public void bar() {
        height = null; // Good
        this.height = null; // Unnecessary qualification

        COUNT++; // Good
        Foo.COUNT++; // Unnecessary qualification

        height = TEN; // Fine
        height = BigDecimal.TEN; // Fine
        height = Foo.FIVE; // Fine; increases clarity by distinguishing it from similar imported static variables
        height = FIVE; // Fine; perhaps the additional clarification is unnecessary
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> A method can be static and non static. Similarly, inside a method, variables can be static and non static. Inside a it's own class and inside an other class also need to take into consideration. Let's see all the scenario now.

### **Inside a Static method**

- **Static variable** can be accessed by

1. In same class, either by `variable name` or `class name.variable name`.
2. In different class, only by `class name.variable name`.

- **Instance variable** can be accessed by

1. In same class, by **object of same class**. (i.e) `object.variable name`.
2. In  different class, must be by **object of relevant class**. (i.e) `object.variable name`.

### **Inside a Instance method(Non static method)**

- **Static variable** can be accessed by

1. In same class, either by `variable name` or `class name.variable name`.
2. In different class, only by `class name.variable name`.

- **Instance variable** can be accessed by

1. In same class, only by `variable name`.
2. In different class, must be by **object of relevant class**.
   (i.e) `object.variable name`.